# reset prefetch count in Listener (rabbitmq, spring-amqp)

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm using spring-amqp.

How can I reset the prefetch count in the listener which implements ChannelAwareMessageListener.

```
public class TestListener implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws IOException {
           channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);

           if (some conditions) {
              // the prefetch count has been initialized to 1 in the SimpleMessageListenerContainer
              // here I want to reset the prefetch count
              channel.basicQos(10, true); // not working, I want to request 10 messages next time

              // I can do this way, following code work as expected, but is this the right way?
              container.stop(); // SimpleMessageListenerContainer
              container.setPrefetchCount(10);
              container.start();
           }
    }
}
```

In short, I want to reset the prefetch count dynamically in the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the prefetch on a channel will only affect new consumers created on that channel. The existing consumer gets the qos prefetch that was on the channel at the time it was created.

Yes, stopping and restarting the container will work.

However, you should not do that on the listener thread, you should use a task executor for the stop/start; otherwise the stop() will be delayed by 5 seconds (by default) waiting for the consumer threads to return to the container (hence you shouldn't run `stop()` on the listener thread).

Or you can reduce the `shutdownTimeout`